# How can I implement a recursive neural network in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, c++, neural-network, tensorflow

Is there some way of implementing a recursive neural network like the one in [[Socher et al. 2011]](http://www.socher.org/index.php/Main/ParsingNaturalScenesAndNaturalLanguageWithRecursiveNeuralNetworks) using TensorFlow?
Note that this is different from recurrent neural networks, which are nicely supported by TensorFlow.
The difference is that the network is not replicated into a linear sequence of operations, but into a tree structure.

I imagine that I could use the `While` op to construct something like a breadth-first traversal of the tree data structure for each entry of my dataset.

Maybe it would be possible to implement tree traversal as a new C++ op in TensorFlow, similar to `While` (but more general)?

Comment: Could you build your graph on the fly after examining each example? Current implementation incurs overhead (maybe 1-50ms per run call each time the graph has been modified), but we are working on removing that overhead and examples are useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, these models are very hard to implement efficiently and cleanly in TensorFlow because the graph structure depends on the input. That also makes it very hard to do minibatching. It is possible using things like the while loop you mentioned, but doing it cleanly isn't easy.

You can build a new graph for each example, but this will be very annoying. If, for a given input size, you can enumerate a reasonably small number of possible graphs you can select between them and build them all at once, but this won't be possible for larger inputs.

You can also route examples through your graph with complicated tf.gather logic and masks, but this can also be a huge pain.

Ultimately, building the graph on the fly for each example is probably the easiest and there is a chance that there will be alternatives in the future that support better immediate style execution. But as of v0.8 I would expect this to be a bit annoying and introduce some overhead as Yaroslav mentions in his comment.

Edit: Since I answered, here is an example using a static graph with while loops: https://github.com/bogatyy/cs224d/tree/master/assignment3
I am not sure how performant it is compared to custom C++ code for models like this, although in principle it could be batched.

Answer (score 7):

Your guess is correct, you can use `tf.while_loop` and `tf.cond` to represent the tree structure in a static graph. More info:
https://github.com/bogatyy/cs224d/tree/master/assignment3

In my evaluation, it makes training 16x faster compared to re-building the graph for every new tree.

Comment: thanks for the example...works like a charm. Just curious how long did it take to run one complete epoch with all the training examples(as per the Stanford Dataset split) and the machine config you ran the training on. Thanks

Comment: Ivan, how exactly can mini-batching be done when using the static-graph implementation? 
I saw that you've provided a short explanation, but could you elaborate further?
Thanks!