# Does Tensorflow's tf.while_loop automatically capture dependencies when executing in parallel?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, tensorflow, parallel-processing

I am interested in implementing a Recursive Neural Network in Tensorflow, like what has been done in [How can I implement a recursive neural network in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054188/how-can-i-implement-a-recursive-neural-network-in-tensorflow).

However, in his implementation, the `parallel_iterations` of the `tf.while_loop` statement was fixed to be 1. I fear that this might be too slow. Since the tree I am going to feed into tensorflow have parts that are not dependent on each other, I would hope that I could set `parallel_iterations` to a higher value. However, it is inevitable that there are some dependencies required in the tree I feed in as input to tensorflow, and I am afraid that setting it to higher value may break the dependency property.

So my question is, had Tensorflow's `tf.while_loop` automatically captured dependencies already, in order to only use paralleism on placed that are not dependent on each other?

The tensorflow documentation says the following:

> For correct programs, while_loop should return the same result for any
>   parallel_iterations > 0.

But I am not sure what they mean by "correct programs".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can.

according to this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1984), ops will run in parallel once all their inputs nodes are computed:

> while_loop implements non-strict semantics. An iteration can start as soon as one of the ops for this iteration is ready (i.e., all its inputs are available.) for execution. So a while_loop can easily have multiple iterations running in parallel. For example, for scan, even if the accumulated value is not available in a step, the step can still start and execute any ops that don't depend on the accumulated value.

so you shouldn't encounter any issues.